# Most efficient way to take max of classifier scores in Python and / or PySpark

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, data-science

I have a dataframe with the scores of a two-class classification model...

| Observation | Class | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0.5013 |
| 1 | 1 | 0.4987 |
| 2 | 0 | 0.5010 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.4990 |
| 3 | 0 | 0.5128 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.4872 |

I only care about the "winning" class (either 0 or 1) and its corresponding probability (the max. probability). What is the best way to group or modify this dataframe to only have 3 observations (in this case) with the "winning" class (0 or 1) and the "winning" probability?

For example, my desired output...

| Observation | Class | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0.5013 |
| 2 | 0 | 0.5010 |
| 3 | 0 | 0.5128 |

Answer (score 0):

To select some rows in a df by some rule you can use .loc or .query:

timing: 300 µs ± 6 µs per loop

```
df.loc[df['Class']==0]
```

timing: 1.17 ms ± 53 µs per loop

```
df.query('Class == 0')
```

Comment: Thanks @George. I basically want to "flatten" the first dataframe at the top into the second dataframe at the bottom.  So I want to keep one unique record for each observation, but only have the "max" probability score and the class that that specific probability score corresponds to (in other words, I'm getting both 2 scores for both classes right now, and I just want one score for the winner... along with its class)

Comment: Got it. Try this:

First you need to group by class and aggregate probability. Then join needed value for observation since you can't aggregate by this column.

df1 = df.groupby('Class', as_index=False)['prob'].max()
df2 = df1.join(df.loc[:, 'observation'])

Answer (score 0):

Pandas allows filtering the dataframe in an `argmax()`-like fashion with respect to the `Probability` column by sorting in an ascending fashion via  [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)  and retrieving those row indices that coincide with the highest (predicted) `Probability` per `Observation` index. Here's the code

```py
df = df.loc[df.drop('Class', axis=1).sort_values(by = ['Observation', 'Probability'], ascending = [True, False])[['Observation']].drop_duplicates(keep="first").index]
```

and yields

```py
df
>     Observation  Class  Probability
 0            1      0       0.5013
 2            2      0       0.5010
 4            3      0       0.5128
```

Answer (score 0):

In [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark), you can create a struct of the `probability` and `class` fields and take a max of that.

```
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('observation'). \
    agg(func.max(func.struct('probability', 'class')).alias('max_prob_class_struct')). \
    select('observation', 'max_prob_class_struct.*'). \
    show()

# +-----------+-----------+-----+
# |observation|probability|class|
# +-----------+-----------+-----+
# |          1|     0.5013|    0|
# |          3|     0.5128|    0|
# |          2|      0.501|    0|
# +-----------+-----------+-----+
```

The `max` here first checks the first element, which is `probability` in this case, and then the second element (in case of a clash). In case both classes have the same probability, the `1` is selected due to the `max` (max of 0 & 1).